# A list in a function should return several outcome, amoung them a data frame

Tags: r

I want this function to return a list, first the name of the column and then the data frame. But it doesnt work to return the data frame. It seem to be something with the size of the data frame to fit the list. But Im not sure how to fix this...

```
set.seed(1)
a <- rnorm(1:5,0,1)
b <- rnorm(1:5,0,1)
c <- rnorm(1:5,0,1)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c)


test <- function(i){
num <- list()
num[1] <- colnames(df)[i]
num[2] <- df
return(num)
}
test(1)
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
[1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808  0.3295078
Warning message:
In num[2] <- df :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: You need to index also `num[2] <- df[i]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to return value of only that respective column?

Try :

```
test <- function(df, i){
  list(name = colnames(df)[i], value = df[[i]])
}

test(df, 1)
#$name
#[1] "a"

#$value
#[1] -0.63  0.18 -0.84  1.60  0.33
```

Comment: Ok!  But if I want to return the whole data frame?

Comment: do you want to return whole dataframe as a vector or dataframe? If as a vector use `list(name = colnames(df)[i], value = unlist(df, use.names = FALSE))` Or as dataframe use `list(name = colnames(df)[i], value =df)`

Comment: The outcome may seem weird, but this is just an example of another dataset I'm working with